# Inconsistent Windows command interactions with ADS

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, filesystems

I'm trying to figure out if this used to work in the past at some point. (Requires >= Windows 8) in a command prompt you can add filestreams (Alternate Data Streams) knows as ADS and inspect them.

```
$>echo I am a regular text file nothing going on here > file1.txt
$>echo I am a hidden filestream > file1.txt:another
$> more < file1.txt:another
I am a hidden filestream

$> type file1.txt:another
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

And there it blows up.
But in PowerShell that last command works just fine if you '.\' qualify the filename correctly.

```
$>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
$> type .\file1.txt:another
I am a hidden filestream
```

Here it works, what gives? Did this used to work in command prompt in the past? Some example blogs and tutorials on the Internet seem to indicate that it once did work. I was trying to eliminate the personal firewall being a factor here, but since the more command works, the firewall is not actually hiding the stream. I also noted that starting of a binary hidden inside a stream no longer appears to work either, and wonder if the behaviour change is a hotfix, and that M$ may have forgotten about the harder to abuse more command workaround, but find that slightly unlikely.

**Update:**

Turns out It was alwys this way, "type" never did support streams @dxiv is right , see also https://blog.foldersecurityviewer.com/ntfs-alternate-data-streams-the-good-and-the-bad/

Comment: Some `cmd` commands recognize ADS filestreams, though not all, and `type` is among those that don't. See for example [this answer](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=6623#p6623).

Comment: I re-read the article I first found and it does back up the fact that it was always this way too. Thanks @dxiv . That is a correct comment/answer.